# Force a repair of Star Wars: The Old Republic

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I successfully downloaded/installed Star Wars: The Old Republic (SW-TOR) and ran it. But, I uninstalled it to try to fix something else. Before I uninstalled it, I made a backup of most of the files in another directory.

Within a day (i.e. no additional release patch between first and second installs), I decided to re-install it with the web installer again. I restored the files I had to the directory to which I installed it, and then ran the client.

It appears that I didn't back up a few essential files because the launcher wants to re-download everything. Unfortunately, I can't select the "Repair" option in the Launcher Settings, either, because it doesn't acknowledge that I've completed a patch download.

**Mainly, I want to know how to download only the files I would need.**

I would think that the Launcher would detect that I have all of the files for the *Assets*, *Movies*, and *swtor* directories, which constitute over 99% of all of the data I need. But, it doesn't detect this, which leads me to believe that a "Repair" would fix this, except I can't run it.

If indeed I have no other option outside of a Repair, how to I trick the Launcher to enable the *Repair* option?

`FixLauncher.exe` only fixes the Launcher, but not the full repair.

Comment: `I made a backup of most of the files in another directory.` What didn't you back up? It should work perfectly well if you back up everything, so keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: The version files appear to be encrypted and signed, and I can't see any way to start the launcher with some sort of repair argument ... I think you may be out of luck.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I saved all of the sub-directories, but not the files in the root installation directory. Yes, I should have saved everything, but I'm asking this question because I didn't.

Comment: Is it definitely trying to download those files again? I seem to recall that these sorts of things don't check for a files existence alone but check the contents via checksums (I assume) quite thoroughly. This means that even if the file exists it can take time to verify it... To answer your question you could ask a friend for all the stuff in the root directory if you have somebody that is in a position to do so. I wouldn't trust a stranger off the internet for these sorts of executables though, of course. :)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that, without the corresponding `.version` files*, you can't force the Launcher to repair the game files. Since I had not saved any `.version` files, I could not do anything but re-download the entire game client.

However, as Chris mentioned in the question comments, if I could have accessed anybody's copy of these files (about 50 kB in total), I could have skipped the full download.

* - at the time of answer, the important version files (the others download very quickly) are:

- `assets_swtor_main.version`
- `assets_swtor_[language]_[culture].version` (`[language]` and `[culture]` are language/culture identifiers, e.g. `assets_swtor_en_us.version` for en-US)
- `movies_[language]_[culture].version`
- `retailclient_swtor.version`

A [Base64](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) ([decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Decode/Default.aspx)) string of a ZIP file containing the `assets_swtor_main.version` and `retailclient_swtor.version` files from 1.3.4 (2012-07-24):

```
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
```

Comment: Note: Since I can't post more than 30000 characters, I couldn't produce a Base64 string for all of the `.version` files. I may post them in another answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to force a repair (or update), delete the bitraider folder.  My problem was patch 3.3.2 would not update so I did this and it worked.

Source: http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=786461